# How to rig a bot's command to only a certain user

Tags: discord.py

I've been making this pp size machine, which is somewhat like dank memer's one

```
@client.command()
async def pp(ctx,member : discord.Member):
  size=random.randint(1,10)
  message = "8"
  for x in range (size):
    message= message + "="
    if x == size-1:
      message = message + "D"
  if member == "PROTATO#6826":
    message = "8D"
  ppsize = discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.orange(), title=f"PP size",description=f"""{member}'s penis 
    {message}        """)
  await ctx.send(embed = ppsize)
```

But i want to rig the command for a certain user to only show "8D" instead of the random lengths.

But no matter what it is the

```
if member == "PROTATO#6826":
    message = "8D"
```

code doesnt run or gets over looked?
Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack okbye! Do you have the member's id? If you do, you can use [`member.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member%20id#discord.Member.id) and compare it with what you have.

Comment: I have no clue what is that, do u mind explaining and how i should imply that code to my own?

Comment: I will write an answer. If it doesn't help, do comment on it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the member mentioned has the same id as a specific user. You can either [enable developer mode](https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/store#:%7E:text=Open%20up%20the%20Discord%20app,and%20enter%20your%20application%20ID) on discord, or you can print the [`member.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member%20id#discord.Member.id) at the very beginning. Do view a code example below.

```py
@client.command()
async def pp(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    print(member.id) # this would print a user's unique id
    message = "Hey!"
    if member.id == 394506589350002688: # replace this id with what was printed at the start
        message = "Hello!"
    await ctx.send(message)
```

[image: Image of code above]

**Similar Questions**:

- [How to check if message was sent by certain user?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207112/14420546) - SO
- [How do I detect if the message is sent by a specific user id?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66395383/14420546) - SO